# Laplace Operator is symmetric

Tags: calculus, probability, functional-analysis

In Morters-Peres, Brownian motion, Theorem 2.51 want to prove a specific process $X$ is a martingale, the proof requires a fact that
$$\int p(u,B(s),x)\Delta f(x)dx=\int \Delta p(u,B(s),x)f(x)dx,$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian and $$p(u,B(s),\cdot):\mathbb{R}^{d}\to \mathbb{R}$$
is given by
$$p(u,B(s),x)=(2\pi u)^{-\frac{d}{2}}\exp(-\frac{|B(s)-x|^2}{2u})$$
and $f:\mathbb{R}^{d}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a twice continuously differentiable function. The textbook said the equality only requires the integration by parts. But I don't get it. Can someone show me the details? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly notice that you have $p(u,B(s),\cdot) \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ since $p(u,B(s),x) \to 0$ for $\vert x \vert \to \infty$.

Now let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and $f \in C^2(\mathbb R^d)$. Then we get by integration by parts (or Green's theorem) that

\begin{align*}
\int \varphi(x) \cdot \Delta f(x) \, dx = \int \langle \nabla \varphi(x) , \nabla f(x) \rangle_2 \, dx = \int \Delta\varphi(x) \cdot f(x) \, dx,
\end{align*}
which follows since you have $\varphi(x) \to 0$ for  $\vert x \vert \to \infty$. Since $p(u,B(s),\cdot) \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$  you get the disered statement :)

Comment: Can you show the details of the integration by parts? I can only remember the one variable case, no idea about the multivariable.

Comment: Honestly I don't know the details. I just know that the above equality is frequently used in functional analysis and PDE (especially in the theory of sobolev spaces). As far as I know the details involve vector calculus, which gets quickly pretty messy. If you want to go further into these things, I would search for Green's Theorem or Gauß's theorem (if your domain is well behaved).